How can I get the last row and column from a Google Sheet connected to BigQuery
I have few scheduled queries that run once per month to populate a BigQuery datasets, which each one is connected to an sheet. Then, my goal is to copy the content from a Google Sheet connected with this BigQuery, to another spreadsheet file, using App Script.
The problem is: Some features from Sheets is not supported when we're using datasource sheet (connected to BigQuery), which make a little more difficult since I need find alternative ways to few problems. My current problem is try to get the last row and column from the datasource sheet, which obviously I tried getLastRow() and getLastColumn() but I got the error: Exception: The action is not supported for DATASOURCE sheet..
Meanwhile, I tested the getRange() and it works since I know the last row and column, but the getDataRange() doesn't, is not supported too.
I know there is a similar question to this from here: Using BigQuery connected sheet in Apps Script, but since was not answered and I bring a more detailed info and tries about what is supported or not, I guess would complement to the resolution of problem.
Well my last try is here:
const idTargetSpreadSheet = "SECRET";
const targetInitialLine = 3;

function collectDataToReport() {
  const spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const allSheets = spreadSheet.getSheets().map(s => s.getName());
  const targetSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(idTargetSpreadSheet);

  allSheets.forEach(sheetName => {
    if (sheetName == 'zero') return;

    Logger.log(`Copying data from ${sheetName}...`);

    let sheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName(sheetName)
    // The error happens here when I try to get last row or column
    let lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
    let lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();

    try {
      data = sheet.getRange(`A1:${columnToLetter(lastColumn)}${lastRow}`).getValues();

      let soted_column = getSortedColumn(sheetName);
      data.sort(function (a, b) {
        return b[soted_column] - a[soted_column];
      });

      const targetRange = targetSpreadSheet.getSheetByName(convertSheetName(sheetName))
                                           .getRange(targetInitialLine, 1, lastRow, lastColumn);

      targetRange.setValues(data);
    } catch(err) {
      Logger.log(`Error while collecting data from ${sheetName}: ${err}`);
    }
  })
}

function columnToLetter(column) {
  let temp, letter = '';
  while (column > 0) {
    temp = (column - 1) % 26;
    letter = String.fromCharCode(temp + 65) + letter;
    column = (column - temp - 1) / 26;
  }
  return letter;
}

function convertSheetName(sheetName) {
  data = {
    'dataset1': 'newSheetName1',
    'dataset2': 'newSheetName2'
  }

  return data[sheetName];
}

function getSortedColumn(sheetName) {
  data = {
    'dataset1': 5,
    'dataset2': 5
  }

  return data[sheetName];
}

Can someone help me to get last column from datasource sheet?

There is no Sheet.getColumns() method. Use Sheet.getLastColumn() instead.

Yeah, you're right @doubleunary, I wrote wrong in the example, but tested the correct one, fixed.

After few hours trying to find a solution, finally did it!
As I said in the question, we cannot use some function from the Sheet Class because it is not supported by the Datasource Sheet. The trick is to get them through the getRange() function using the N1 notation to get the last row and the last column.
let lastRow = sheet.getRange('A1:A').getValues().filter(String).length;
let lastColumn = sheet.getRange('A1:1').getValues().filter(String).flat().length;


This will only give the correct result as long as every cell in column A and row 1 contain a value. If there are blank cells in between, the count will be off.

On my case this is not a problem, but If you need include blank cells I guess removing the .filter(String) should be enough too. @doubleunary

Nope, that will not get the correct result. Use Array.findLastIndex() instead.
